# Is it safe to store jwt in a variable in flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, jwt

I wanna know, is it safe to store the jwt token in a variable? so it can be used during app for requests, or maybe there's a better way?

Answer (score -1):

Keychain / Keystore would be the best option. Checkout flutter_secure_storage:

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage